# Difference between parent(); and offsetParent();

Tags: jquery, traversal

im wondering what is the difference between traversing operators - parent(); and offsetParent(); in Jquery. It seems to me that they are doing same thing.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, offSetParent returns the parent on which the elements orientation depends.
If your element is positioned absolutely, the returned offsetParent is the ancestor element with the relative position, which is not necessarily the direct parent.

The example on [jQuery API offsetParent](http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/) shows how the offsetParent traverses and skips over an unpositioned parent.